# Hypertable SELECT IN clause

Tags: select, hql, hypertable

I was trying to dO:
    SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ROW IN ('1232', '2341', '3245');

It threw an exception,

```
Error: Hypertable::Exception: Column predicate name not identical with selected column - HYPERTABLE HQL parse error
```

But, this works,

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE (ROW='971443272' or ROW='968695147' or ROW='977683398' or ROW='97937558');
```

Why is it designed this way?

NOTE: I have seen similar question but other question were trying
find, if not 'IN', then, what's alternate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypertable currently does not support WHERE ROW IN.  The Exception that was thrown is incorrect and we've filed an issue for it. The alternate method is WHERE (ROW='971443272' or ROW='968695147' or ROW='977683398' or ROW='97937558')

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I did the same.